# como utilizar arraylist

Tags: java

tengo una duda sobre el uso de Arraylists, debo hacer un proyecto en el cual debo almacenar pedidos en un arraylist que me entrega un archivo excel, tengo la clase main y la clase pedido, cada pedido con sus respectivos atributos, pero mi duda es, ¿Dónde debo instanciar el arraylist? ¿Debo instanciarlo en la clase main, para en esa misma clase ir agregando los pedidos que voy obteniendo de la lectura del excel(la cual se hace en la clase main)? o ¿Debo instanciarla en la clase pedido, pero creando una interface "List"?
Ayudaaaaa por favor!

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Dónde debo instanciar el arraylist?

Donde necesites hacerlo. Una clase puede ser instanciada en donde necesites hacerlo, no tienes que darle más vueltas. Sin embargo, esta *"necesidad"* se irá convirtiendo en estándar sobre en qué lugar instanciar ciertas clases. Por ejemplo, cuando aprendas sobre patrones de diseño, verás que ciertas clases pertenecientes a `X` dominio es mejor instanciarlas en `Y` dominio.

En tu caso, que estás simulando una base de datos, esa lista es mejor encerrarla en una clase que indique su propósito. Por ejemplo:

```
public class Store {

    public static final List<Product> items;

    static {
         items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Product save(Product p) {
        items.add(p);
        return p;
    }

    public int count() {
        return itens.size();
    }
}
```

Semánticamente está mejor que solo instanciar una lista:

```
Store store = new Store();
store.save(product);
```

> ¿Debo instanciarla en la clase pedido, pero creando una interface "List"?

No tiene que ver una cosa con otra. Instanciar mediante la interfaz `List` tiene objetivos polimórficos. Dado que ésta interfaz tiene muchas implementaciones, puedes guardar en un objeto `List` una instancia de `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `SortedList`, etc.

Te recomiendo aprender bien la teoría de la programación y diseño orientado a objetos. Es mucho más que clases y objetos y te ayudará a comprender distintas situaciones más adelante.